# Efficiently split pandas dataframe based on combinations of one column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, combinations

Lets say I have a dataframe with one column and it has 3 unique values

**[Click here to see input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CgmR.png)**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c'], columns = ['string'])
df
```

I want to split this dataframe into smaller data frames, such that each dataframe will contain 2 unique values. In the above case I need 3 data frames 3c2(nCr) = 3. df1 - [a b] df2 - [a c] df3 - [b c]. Please click on the below link to see my current implementation.

**[Click here to see current code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1I89.png)**

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.combinations(df.string.values, 2):
    print(df[df.string.isin(i)], '\n')
```

I am looking something like groupby in pandas. Because sub-setting data inside loop is time consuming. In one of the sample case, I have 609 unique values and it was taking around 3 mins to complete the loop. So, looking for some optimized way to perform the same operation, as the unique values may shoot up to 1000's in real scenarios.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Many of us are not allowed to go to imgr and other sites. Could you post the screen shots here? Or even better, post the actual code and output? That way, we won't have to retype your code to test our solution (and you'll be more likely to get an answer).

Comment: @rajah9 Sorry! Now, I have added the code block in question. I dont have enough reputation to add images.

Answer (score 0):

It will be slow because you're creating 370k dataframes. If all of them are supposed to only hold two values, why does it need to be a dataframe?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(100)})
df['key'] = 1
records = df.merge(df, on='key').drop('key', axis=1).to_dict('r')
[pd.Series(x) for x in records]
```

You will see that `records` is computed quite fast but then it takes a few minutes to generate all of these series objects.

Comment: Hi @rudolfovic - Thanks for the response. It will have 2 unique values, not 2 values. That is the reason I choose dataframe. I have termed 1 column for simplicity, in reality the data will have many other columns.